# RegistrationIds Expiring After an Hour

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am having a weird issue where I can send pushes through GCM to one device for about an hour. After this point I get a RegistrationIds expired event back and the device no longer receives pushes. I have kept the specific app closed on my device to ensure that there is no chance for a new RegistrationId to be created. Any ideas on what I can do so that this doesn't happen? I am using PushSharp to send these notifications.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your android device getting a new InstanceID token before it stops receiving messages? If something is triggering the InstanceID token of the application on the device to change then the previous token would not be valid. Here is an example of checking for expired InstanceID token: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyInstanceIDListenerService.java

Comment: I am actually still using gcm.register() to create and maintain the registration id's. Do you think that this could be the problem?